# Итератор для std::set

Tags: c++

Необходимо написать класс итератор для `std::set`. Каким образом написать конструктор, чтобы в итоге он хранил указатель на элемент множества?
 Например, для вектора можно передать `&v[0]` и сохранить, а тут как?

Comment: А чем не устраивает обычный `std::set::iterator`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb всем устраивает. Задание такое. кЛаСснЫй нИк

Comment: Подумалось - а насколько вообще можно написать итератор без знания внутренностей класса контейнера? В нетривиальном случае?

Comment: Понимайте в чем проблема, итератор в стиле stl имитирует поведение указателей. `std::set` использует двунаправленные итераторы. Для них нужно определить операторы `++` и `--`. Чтобы перемещаться от одного элемента к другому нужно знать внутреннюю структуру контейнера. У вас у ней доступа нет

Comment: @Harry сам указатель лежит где-то на 5 уровне в реализации от MSVC

Comment: Я не собираюсь в сете ничего менять, использую класс, хранящий std::set

Comment: Вашу задачу можно решить только одним способом, писать обертку над `std::set::iterator`. По-другому перемещаться от одного элемента к другому никак.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb ещё можно написать свою реализацию set)

Comment: @pavel и свою реализацию `std::`, куда этот `set` поместить.

Comment: @петя, Вы то, может быть, и "не собираетесь", а задание этого требует - вмешательства во внутренности ```std::set```.